# Returning for loop inside a while loop in python

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, return

I'm trying to make a function that returns this:

```
42334
44423
21142
14221
```

From this:

```
polje = [[1, 2, 4, 4], [4, 1, 4, 2], [2, 1, 4, 3], [2, 4, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

The function just goes through the lists and prints their elements starting with the last ones. I've been able to get the right result by printing, but i'm trying to make it so that the function simply returns the result. How do i do it? I've tried generators, single line for loops etc. but notes on the internet are not plentiful and are often writen in a complicated way...

Here's the code i've got so far:

```
def izpisi(polje):
    i = len(polje[0]) - 1
    while i >= 0:
        for e in polje:
            print(e[i], end="")
        i -= 1
        print("\n")
    return 0
```

Comment: Instead of printing, try saving the values in one element. Then add that element into an array/list.

Comment: Do you want that to be a `generator` function ?

Comment: Yea, i guess. I just need the function to return the proper values instead of printing them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def izpisi(polje):
    return '\n'.join([ # inserts '\n' between the lines
        ''.join(map(str, sublst)) # converts list to string of numbers
        for sublst in zip(*polje) # zip(*...) transposes your matrix
    ][::-1]) # [::-1] reverses the list

polje = [[1, 2, 4, 4], [4, 1, 4, 2], [2, 1, 4, 3], [2, 4, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
print izpisi(polje)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> polje = [[1, 2, 4, 4], [4, 1, 4, 2], [2, 1, 4, 3], [2, 4, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
>>> def izpisi(polje):
        return zip(*map(reversed, polje))

>>> for line in izpisi(polje):
        print(*line, sep='')


42334
44423
21142
14221
```

`zip(*x)` transposes a matrix. However you start at the last column so I simply add `map(reversed,)` to handle that.

The rest is just printing each line.

Comment: You're using python2, i targeted this code at OP who is using Py3. First do `from __future__ import print_function`

Comment: The problem is that this is still printing... I need it to work in a way that if i do print(izpisi(polje)), it will return 
42334
44423
21142
14221

Comment: Here you go: `return '\n'.join(''.join(map(str, x)) for x in zip(*map(reversed, polje)))`. Note that it's much better to print line by line then keep a potentially big string in memory

Answer (score 1):

you can change your code to store the items in a `list` instead of print them.
and store each `list` in another `list` in order to return all of them.

like this:

```
def izpisi(polje):
    a = []
    i = len(polje[0]) - 1
    while i >= 0:
        l = []
        for e in polje:
            l.append(e[i])
        i -= 1
        a.append(l)
    return a
```